# Hyperlinking or linking in another way to a cell without it being able to change

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

How do I hyperlink or link to a cell from another cell in a way that when rows are added, and the row numbers keeps changing due to new rows of information being added throughout the sheet, the link cell address doesn't change?

I have added a hyperlink, but if a row is added above the cell I am linking to, then the link goes to the cell above it as it is set to the row number at present and not the cell.

I want to go to a set cell by clicking on one cell and no matter where that cell moves to, it still takes me to that cell.

Thank you for your time and effort.

Answer (score 0):

Define a named for the hyperlink target cell, then set the hyperlink to that named range. When rows are inserted or deleted, the named range will still point to the correct cell.

[image]

Comment: glad it helped. Please mark the post as the answer.